# Array parameters in Facebook REST APIs

Tags: api, facebook, rest

I'd like to use the REST APIs to invite friends to an event.
So far I managed to do it but I am performing a request to the API for every friend while it is possible to passo to the method a list of friends.
http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/rest/events.invite

How do I have to encode the list of identifiers?

Comment: I'd like to know this too, why can't I set a bounty?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about obsolete API functionality which is not commonly used by programmers